# Rationalize the Denominator by Default

Tags: output-formatting

In Mathematica 7, if I input Sqrt[2/7], Mathematica outputs $\sqrt{\frac{2}{7}}$, but I want it to output $\frac{\sqrt{14}}{7}$ instead. How do I make Mathematica output values without radicals in the denominator by default? I already tried [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1999/Jul/msg00250.html) solution without success:

```
rat[p_] := If[FreeQ[Denominator[p], Power[_, Rational[_, _]]], 0, 1]
FullSimplify[Sqrt[2/7], ComplexityFunction -> rat]
```

I guess I need a better ComplexityFunction, and some way to have Mathematica output the rationalized form by default, instead of having to explicitly use FullSimplify every time.

edit: It would be great if the solution also worked for more complex expressions. For example:
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\rightarrow\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{5-2\sqrt{3}}\rightarrow\frac{5}{13}+\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{13}$

Comment: I solved it for the three examples you gave. Other cases can be handled through additional replacement rules.

Comment: An obvious question is why you want to rationalize the denominator? Yes, I know we were taught in school to do that, but it's not always the best thing. Even in calculus when, e.g, you calculate certain limits, the method involves rationalizing a numerator thereby unrationalizing ("irrationalizing"?) the numerator.

Comment: @murray: I'm studying circuit analysis by solving practice problems, and the reference answers are in this form.

Comment: @mv: you can always apply Simplify to your answer (and, if necessary, to the reference answers) to see if they're the same -- without having to rationalize the denominators.

Comment: I believe this has a solution (by [David E Speyer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1200/david-e-speyer)) [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9893/35000)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the old days, when "making the Numerator rational" was often wanted, I came up with the following set of rules:

```
EvaluiereAt[pos:(_Integer|{__Integer}),f_:Identity][expr_]:=
  ReplacePart[expr,pos->Extract[expr,pos,f]];
EvaluiereAt[pos:{{__Integer}..},f_:Identity][expr_] :=
  Fold[ReplacePart[#1, #2 -> Extract[#1, #2, f]] &, expr, Reverse[Sort[pos]]];

$pinkHoldColor = ColorData["HTML"]["HotPink"];
pinkHold[x_] := Style[Tooltip[HoldForm[x], "held"], $pinkHoldColor];

Attributes[rootRational] = {Listable};
rootRational[expr_] := 
  Module[{zw, res, pos}, zw = expr /. Sqrt[a_] :> Sqrt[Together[a]];
   res = zw /. Sqrt[a_/b_] :> Sqrt[Expand[a b]]/b;
   res = res /. {a_./(b_ + d_. Sqrt[c_]) -> (a (b - d Sqrt[c]))/(b^2 -
           d^2 c), 
      a_./(b_ - d_. Sqrt[c_]) -> (a (b + d Sqrt[c]))/(b^2 - d^2 c)};
   res = res /. Sqrt[Rational[a_, b_]] :> pinkHold[Sqrt[a b]]/b;
   res = res /. (a_/Sqrt[b_]) :> a pinkHold[Sqrt[b]]/b;
   res = res /. 
     b_. Power[a_, Rational[-1, 2]] :> b pinkHold[Sqrt[a]]/a;
   pos = Position[res, _?NumberQ];
   If[Flatten[pos] =!= {}, res = EvaluiereAt[pos][res]];
   res];

Attributes[pinkUnhold] = {Listable};
pinkUnhold[expr_] := 
  ReleaseHold[expr /. Style[Tooltip[a_, __], __] -> a];
```

the function `rootRational` tries to achieve this. To show, that something is in `HoldForm`, I marked it with a pink color. To `ReleaseHold` and take away the color an tooltip there is the function `pinkUnhold`.

Examples:

```
w = Sqrt[6]/9 
% // rootRational 
% // pinkUnhold Clear[a]; 
w = Sqrt[(1 + a)/(1 - a)] // rootRational 
% // FullSimplify 
rootRational[Sqrt[b]/b] 
rootRational[1/Sqrt[b]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Could you add the definition of EvaluiereAt to your answer? After finding it [here](http://www.pbreitfeld.de/brfAdd.m), this solution worked best so far.

Comment: @rmv sorry I missed to copy this definition. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Nice feature. I would like to point out that `w = Sqrt[(1 + a)^3/(1 - a)/(1 - b)] // rootRational` fails in some sense. `w = Sqrt[(1 + a)^3/(1 - a)/(1 - b)] // PowerExpand//rootRational` gives the expected answer if `a<1` and `b<1`

Comment: If you look into the code, you'll see, that the rules are made for squareroots. I made this for teaching purposes, not to be an ever working solution.

Answer (score 11):

I guess the normal evaluation-process will always convert this back to $\sqrt{2/7}$ unless you hold the form explicitly. Converting your expression into the desired form can be done with `Numerator` and `Denominator` which luckily give the desired values of $\sqrt{14}$ and $7$.

```
Divide @@ (HoldForm /@ {Numerator[#], Denominator[#]} &[Sqrt[2/7]])
```

In the moment you release the `HoldForm` the expression gets evaluated back to $\sqrt{2/7}$.

Comment: Perhaps this is clearer: `rat = {Power[Rational[n_, d_], Rational[1, 2]] :>   
    Sqrt[n d]/HoldForm[d]};

Sqrt[2/7] /. rat`

Comment: @DavidCarraher Nice, but its a different concept - I think it deserves to be posted as an answer, not comment.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov  Ok, I posted it.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to specifically handle expressions that are visually displayed as radicals, the most robust method I know is to manipulate the Box structure itself.  Here is one way to do that using the method proposed by halirutan.

```
$PrePrint = 
  ToExpression[
    ToBoxes[#] /. 
     x_SqrtBox :> 
      ToBoxes[
        Divide @@ HoldForm /@ {Numerator@#, Denominator@#} & @ ToExpression @ x
      ]
  ] &;
```

Answer (score 4):

Below are two ways to approach the problem. You could use a replacement rule with `HoldForm`:

```
rat1 = {Sqrt[Rational[n_, d_]] :>   Sqrt[n d]/HoldForm[d], 
        1/Sqrt[x_] :> Sqrt[x]/HoldForm[x], 
        1/(a_ + (b_ Sqrt[c_]) ) :> a/(a^2 - b^2 c) - (b Sqrt[c])/(a^2 - b^2 c)};
```

Or you could use `FractionBox`:

```
rat2 = {Sqrt[Rational[n_, d_]] :> DisplayForm@FractionBox[Sqrt[n d], d], 
        1/Sqrt[x_] :> DisplayForm@FractionBox[Sqrt[x], x], 
        1/(a_ + (b_ Sqrt[c_]) ) :> a/(a^2 - b^2 c) - (b Sqrt[c])/(a^2 - b^2 c)};
```

(The third rule for `rat1` and `rat2` is the same, and requires neither `HoldForm` nor `FractionBox`.)

Testing and showing output below:

```
{Sqrt[2/7], 1/Sqrt[2], 1/(5 - 2 Sqrt[3])} /. rat1
{Sqrt[2/7], 1/Sqrt[2], 1/(5 - 2 Sqrt[3])} /. rat2
```

[image: results]

Comment: `1/(2*Sqrt[2]) /.rat1` doesn't work

Comment: `1/(2*Sqrt[2]) /.rat2` puts the radical on top but doesn't give a simple fraction

Comment: I'll examine this tomorrow and get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

Based on `MinimalPolynomial` for more complicated case:

```
rootRational[fraction_] := 
 Module[{numer = Numerator[fraction], denon = Denominator[fraction], 
   poly, x}, poly = MinimalPolynomial[denon, x]; 
  FullSimplify[Times[numer, Rest[poly]/-x/First[poly] /. x -> denon]]]
```

#### Usage

```
rootRational[1/(Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[5])]
```

[image]

```
rootRational[7/(
 6 - 6 Sqrt[2] + 5 Sqrt[3] + 3 Sqrt[5] - 2 Sqrt[6] - 3 Sqrt[10] + 
  2 Sqrt[15] - Sqrt[30])]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For displaying algebraics where the denominator is a simple radical, you can override the formatting of `Times`/`Power`:

```
Clear[MakeBoxes];
MakeBoxes[a_. Power[b_, r_Rational?Negative], fmt_] := With[
    {p = Mod[r, 1], pow = Quotient[r, 1]},
    MakeBoxes[Times[a, b^pow, Defer[Power[b,p]]], fmt]
]
```

Examples:

```
{1/Sqrt[2], 5/Power[3, (3)^-1], 1/(2+3/Sqrt[5])} //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{5\ 3^{2/3}}{3},\frac{1}{2+\frac{3 \sqrt{5}}{5}}\right\}$

I didn't bother extending this to your more complicated examples, because having:

```
1/(5 - 2 Sqrt[3])
```

automatically display as:

```
5/13 + (2 Sqrt[3])/13
```

would be very confusing (what should `First` return?) Instead, I think it makes much more sense to have a function that converts the expression into a rationalized form, e.g., see question [9868](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9868/45431).

Answer (score 2):

I found this function by Andrzej Kozlowski in the [MathGroup Archive](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1999/Jul/msg00394.html):

```
f1[expr_] :=
  FullSimplify[expr, ComplexityFunction ->
    (
      Count[#, _?
        (MatchQ[Denominator[#], Power[_, _Rational] _. + _.] &),
        {0, Infinity}
      ] + If[FreeQ[#, Root], 0, 1] &
    )
  ]
```

A combination of this, Expand, and Peter Breitfeld's solution seems to work best. E.g.:

test $=\{\frac{2}{3\sqrt{5}},\frac{1}{2-\frac{3}{\sqrt5{}}},\frac{1}{2-\frac{3}{5+\sqrt{7}}}\}$

```
test // f1 // Expand // rootRational
```

$\{\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{15},\frac{10}{11}+\frac{3\sqrt{5}}{11},1-\frac{\sqrt{7}}{7}\}$

Comment: Seems to fail with $\frac 1 {2\sqrt{2}}$