# How can I rationalize the denominator of an expression?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

*Mathematica* doesn't rationalize the denominator automatically, and I haven't found anything in the documentation about it.  But I found an old [post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1999/Jul/msg00250.html) on MathGroup, which proposes a solution using `ComplexityFunction`.

In very simple cases, it works fine, but it fails in more complex cases. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Sorry,I want to give a example,but I am a new user to this site,posting pictures is not allowed.

Comment: I think [this](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/radicals5.htm) is what the OP means

Comment: @bandaoti - You can always upload the image to an upload server and tell us the URI. We'll paste it in the question for you. Alternatively, if you use $\LaTeX$ code you may not need pictures.

Comment: If the OP does really mean the kind of denominator rationalization discussed in http://www.purplemath.com/modules/radicals5.htm, then I would say: (1) rationalizing a denominator is much over-rated -- one of those things that school math teachers try to pound into students' heads and yet is sometimes the very thing that you do *not* want to do (e.g., when finding certain limits of quotients where both numerator and denominator tend to 0); and (2) a denominator-rationalized form may become more complex than the original quotient.

Answer (score 16):

```
RatDenom[x_]:=
  Module[{y,nn,dd,f,g,c,k,blah},
    (y=Together[x];
     nn=Numerator[y];
     dd=Denominator[y];
     f=MinimalPolynomial[dd,t];
     c=f /. t -> 0;
     g=Factor[(c-f)/t];
     {k, blah}=FactorTermsList[Expand[nn*(g /. t -> dd)]];
     Sign[c] ((k/GCD[k,c])*blah)/HoldForm[Evaluate@Abs[c/GCD[k,c]]])]
```

Write $x=\nu/\delta$. The point is that $f(\delta)=0$, so $g(\delta)=c/\delta$. `Expand[]`ing $g(\delta)$ produces an expression without denominators. We call `Together[]` before doing anything else so that `RatDenom[1+1/(Sqrt[2]+1)]` will work.

There are two formatting hacks, both of which were suggested by J.M. in comments on my deleted answer:
The point of the `FactorTermsList[]` is to get `RatDenom[1/(Sqrt[2]+Sqrt[5])]` to output `(-Sqrt[2]+Sqrt[5])/3`, rather than `(-3 Sqrt[2]+3 Sqrt[5])/9`. The `HoldForm[]` is to get `RatDenom[1/Sqrt[2]]` to be `Sqrt[2]/2`, not `1/Sqrt[2]`.

The following output shows the strengths and limitations of this method:

```
(* A straight forward example *)

In[58]:= RatDenom[1/(Sqrt[2]+Sqrt[3]+Sqrt[5])]

         3 Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[30]
Out[58]= --------------------------------
                        12

(* Evaluate[] knows how to multiply expressions with Sqrt[11] *)

In[59]:= RatDenom[(3+Sqrt[11])/(4+Sqrt[11])]

         1 + Sqrt[11]
Out[59]= ------------
              5
(* Nested radicals are fine *)

In[60]:= RatDenom[(2+Sqrt[3])/(1+Sqrt[5+Sqrt[11]])]

Out[60]= (-8 - 4 Sqrt[3] + 2 Sqrt[11] + Sqrt[33] + 8 Sqrt[5 + Sqrt[11]] + 4 Sqrt[3 (5 + Sqrt[11])] - 2 Sqrt[11 (5 + Sqrt[11])] -  Sqrt[33 (5 + Sqrt[11])]) / 5

(* The outermost operation after Together[] must be division. *)

In[65]:= RatDenom[Sqrt[(1+Sqrt[2])/(1+Sqrt[3])]]

              1 + Sqrt[2]
         Sqrt[-----------]
              1 + Sqrt[3]
Out[65]= -----------------
                 1

(* Expand doesn't realize that this numerator equals 1 .*)

In[67]:= RatDenom[Sqrt[3+2 Sqrt[2]]/(1+Sqrt[2])]

           Sqrt[3 + 2 Sqrt[2]] - Sqrt[2 (3 + 2 Sqrt[2])]
Out[67]= -(---------------------------------------------)
                                 1

(* As we can confirm by using N[]. *)

In[68]:= N[%]

         1.
Out[68]= --
         1.
```

Comment: `FullSimplify[ToRadicals[RootReduce[stuff]]]` would work on `Sqrt[3 + 2 Sqrt[2]] - Sqrt[2 (3 + 2 Sqrt[2])]`, but it can sometimes be a crapshoot; I seem to remember some examples where it would rewrite a sum of different radicals as nested radicals instead, but I can't seem to find those examples right now...

Comment: I find this answer great. Notice that adding `ReleaseHold` helps with `1` in denominator and does not convert expression back to the form with root in denominator.

Answer (score 7):

The following works on all the examples in David's answer. It uses the code provided by J.M. in the comments. The transformation is first tried on the whole expression, and if that fails it is applied separately to the numerator and denominator.

```
ratd[x_] := Module[{v},
  v = FullSimplify@ToRadicals@RootReduce@x;
  If[NumberQ[v], v, If[FreeQ[v, Root],
    With[{n = Numerator[v], d = Denominator[v]}, HoldForm[n/d]],
    With[{
      n = FullSimplify@ToRadicals@RootReduce@Numerator@x,
      d = FullSimplify@ToRadicals@RootReduce[1/Denominator@x]
      }, HoldForm[n d]]]]];

test = {1/(Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[5]), (3 + Sqrt[11])/(4 + Sqrt[11]), 
  (2 + Sqrt[3])/(1 + Sqrt[5 + Sqrt[11]]), Sqrt[(1 + Sqrt[2])/(1 + Sqrt[3])], 
  Sqrt[3 + 2 Sqrt[2]]/(1 + Sqrt[2])};

ratd/@test
```

> [image]

Comment: `ratd` fails to do the expected denominator rationalization in simple cases where `RatDenom` succeeds, e.g., with `Sqrt[25/3]`.

Comment: @murray, I'm getting `ratd@Sqrt[25/3] = 5 Sqrt[3]/3` as expected (the same result as RatDenom). That's with *Mathematica* version 8.0.4. What are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting `5/Sqrt[3]`, but that's with a different version of Mathematica.

Comment: It doesn't work on V9 with `test[[1]]` and `test[[4]]`. Maybe this Q&A needs tag with version specification?

Comment: @Kuba, the **question** isn't version specific though - just the answers! Hopefully someone will come up with a method that works for all the test cases, with all versions.

Comment: Yes, you're right. And, yes I would love to see such method.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[rationalize];
SetAttributes[rationalize, Listable];
rationalize[x_] := Block[{den, t, len},
   den = Denominator[x];
   If[NumberQ@den || LeafCount@x <= 5, Return@x];
   len = Length[List @@ Simplify[den]];
   t = List @@ den.# & /@ Take[Tuples[{1, -1}, len], 2^(len - 1)];
   (Times @@ DeleteCases[t, den]*Numerator[x])/Simplify[Times @@ t] // Simplify
];

{(3 + Sqrt[11])/(4 + Sqrt[11]), 1/(Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[5]), 
  (2 + Sqrt[3])/(1 + Sqrt[5 + Sqrt[11]])} // rationalize // rationalize
```

[image]

Comment: On V9 it fails with `1/Sqrt[2] // rationalize`