# How to "rationalize" a fraction in Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions

When I try to rationalize the following number $$1\over{2^{1/4}+4^{1/4}+8^{1/4}}$$

```
   FullSimplify[1/( 2^(1/4)+4^(1/4)+8^(1/4) )]
```

I get the same expression, and not my hand-calculation result which is

$${(\sqrt{4+3\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt 2) (3\sqrt 2  -2)}\over 14$$
What command should I use, if there is one?

Edit:
"rationalize" meaning as in ordinary algebra where roots are moved from denominator to numerator, and not as writing a decimal as a fraction

Comment: `LeafCount[1/(2^(1/4) + 4^(1/4) + 8^(1/4))]` vs. `LeafCount[(Sqrt[4 + 3 Sqrt[2]] - Sqrt[2]) (3 Sqrt[2] - 2)/14]` might give you a hint why this happens. Moreover, "rationalize" is a very misleasing word here.

Comment: I don't know of a command for this.  But people have written functions to do what you wish.  You can find their solutions  here:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/rationalize-the-denominator-by-default 
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9868/how-can-i-rationalize-the-denominator-of-an-expression

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`ToRadicals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals) and [`RootReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootReduce) instead:

```
Simplify @ ToRadicals @ RootReduce[1/(2^(1/4)+4^(1/4)+8^(1/4))] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{1}{14} \left(-6+2 \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2 \left(8+9 \sqrt{2}\right)}\right)$

Comment: Very nice!  Though we should make it clear to the OP that, while the solutions offered here work for his problem, none of them are general.  Consider, for instance:  `test = {1/(Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[5]), (3 + Sqrt[11])/(4 + Sqrt[11]), (2 + Sqrt[3])/(1 + Sqrt[5 + Sqrt[11]]), Sqrt[(1 + Sqrt[2])/(1 + Sqrt[3])], Sqrt[3 + 2 Sqrt[2]]/(1 + Sqrt[2])};`  Given that this is not an obscure problem, yet MMA nevertheless doesn't have a built-in function for this, I gather it must be difficult to create a solution that is sufficiently general for Wolfram to offer it.

Comment: ....Though, having said that, there is such a function in Maple:  https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=rationalize

Comment: @theorist Thanks for the link to Maple. It actually gives answer for variables a,b,c, but oddly enough answer does not look symmetric!

Answer (score 10):

In this case [`ToNumberField`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToNumberField) gives a denested form:

```
ToRadicals[ToNumberField[1/(2^(1/4) + 4^(1/4) + 8^(1/4))]] // Together // TeXForm
```

> $\frac{1}{14} \left(-6+4 \sqrt[4]{2}+2 \sqrt{2}+2^{3/4}\right)$